# ERROR: Not found source for system packages (release 10.04) in APT software sources configuration - Plesk Autoinstaller

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04

I have run the plesk [auto installer](http://www.parallels.com/download/plesk/installer/): `parallels_installer_v3.12.0_build120601.16_os_Ubuntu_10.04_i386` via ssh on my Ubuntu 10.4 LTS 32-bit server.

I get through all the steps, but when it has to start downloading the packages I get 500 errors and then the installer fails.

```
Get:2 http://autoinstall.plesk.com all/all Packages [912B]
Get:3 http://autoinstall.plesk.com all/all Packages [771B]
Fetched 23.6kB in 3s (6102B/s)
Reading package lists...

ERROR: Not found source for system packages (release 10.04) in APT software sources configuration:
Package files:
 100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     release a=now
 500 http://autoinstall.plesk.com/debian/BILLING_11.0.9/ all/all Packages
     origin autoinstall.plesk.com
 500 http://autoinstall.plesk.com/debian/SITEBUILDER_11.0.10/ all/all Packages
     origin autoinstall.plesk.com
 500 http://autoinstall.plesk.com/ubuntu/PSA_11.0.9/ lucid/all Packages
     origin autoinstall.plesk.com
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/tarkus/ubuntu/ hardy/main Packages
     release v=8.04,o=LP-PPA-tarkus,a=hardy,n=hardy,l=PPA for Tom Liu,c=main
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 etc.....
Pinned packages:
```

Just for some background, I upgraded from ubuntu 8.04 to 10.04 last night. Not sure why or how but plesk got removed somehow.

So this is me trying to reinstall it now.

Comment: "So now I have managed to get the autoinstaller working by downloading the file and adding it to the server." What autoinstaller? Which file? What server? Please include the command you are running.

Comment: Please see updated question

Comment: I have exactly the same problem and as it happens I also updated from Ubuntu 8.04 to 10.04.

> Not sure why or how but plesk got removed somehow.
I don't think this is the case. The errors of concern starts at the last line you posted:

> 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/tarkus/ubuntu/ hardy/main Packages
     release v=8.04,o=LP-PPA-tarkus,a=hardy,n=hardy,l=PPA for Tom Liu,c=main
     origin ppa.launchpad.net

On my system I have similar errors, but many referring to "hardy" and "8.04".

So I suspect that now that your OS is upgraded Plesk is still trying to refer to some old files via "8.04".

Comment: indeed, this is what i thought after digging around. You get any luck with fixing it?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that after Debian/Ubuntu upgrades the Plesk keeps on referring to an old version of the OS files. In my case I had to replace all instances of `hardy` with `lucid`. At first I tried doing this in `/etc/apt/sources.list` but something kept on changing it back. The final solution was to change it in `/etc/apt/sources.list.ai_back`.

Here is the solution I found:

"After inspecting autoinstaller3.log again, I've noticed that the autoinstaller uses
/etc/apt/sources.list.ai_back
for apt-get. I've updated the entries in this file also to squeeze and now the autoinstaller is running again."

Reference:
http://forum.parallels.com/showthread.php?258412-Internal-error-in-autoinstaller-after-update-from-lenny-to-squeeze-with-10-4-4